# Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Я использовал [пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/111102/) для своего приложения. Idea не выдает никаких предупреждений, но при запуске я получаю ошибки вида:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [data.xml]
>
> Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/root-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/data.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory

Видимо проблемы с data.xml, но я никак не могу их обнаружить.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   ">

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.databaseUrl}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>

<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

root.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>

<import resource="data.xml"/>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Encoder -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName= org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/shopbase
jdbc.username=user
jdbc.password=1234
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.model.Product" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

И сама модель на всякий случай:

package com.model;

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "price")
private float price;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>shopGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>shopTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <!--Spring-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Все сделано по мануалам.

Comment: [Это поможет?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/445740/197447) Добавьте, пожалуйста, `pom.xml` полностью.

Answer (score 1):

У вас "каша" в `pom.xml`. Все зависимости Spring MVC должны быть одной версии. Смотрите, что получается у вас в classpath в итоге.

```
» mvn dependency:tree 
[INFO] shopGroup:shopTest:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.9.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile
```

Посмотрите последние актуальные версии зависимостей на [Maven Central](https://javalibs.com/). Должно получиться, примерно, так:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>shopGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>shopTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Spring-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- остальные зависимости -->

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Можете воспользоваться примером `pom.xml` из [spring-showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/pom.xml)

Также есть простой способ указать зависимости Spring [через BOM](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-maven-bom) (Bill of Materials)

P.S. Актуальный Hibernate 4.x или 5.x

Comment: Спасибо. Зависимости поправил, но ошибка не исчезла. В моделе Product.java подчеркиваются наименования @Table(name = "product"), то, что в кавычках. Так же у всех @Column.

Comment: @Alex_St Ну я же не добавил в пример зависимости Hibernate, потому что ошибка у вас была связана со Spring. Оставьте те что у вас были, только версию обновите (ссылка в посте).

Comment: Может ли быть проблема в чем то еще, помимо зависимостей? Или мне необходимо дольше поразбираться с этим? Вроде бы все сделал, как Вы сказали, но не помогает. Ошибка все та же(

Comment: Мне отсюда не видно, что у вас там происходит :) Видимо вам просто нужно начать с более базовых примеров. Сначала разберитесь какие зависимости у вас вообще есть в `pom.xml` и зачем, как стартует приложение Spring, как подключается JSP View Resolver, добейтесь чтобы отобразилась простая JSP страница. Потом будете прикручивать Hibernate. А потом уже Spring Security.

Comment: Я делал уже большое приложение для своей выпускной работы в универе, но не использовал Hibernate. Настроил приложение в Idea (так как в ней не работал, до этого делал все в еклипсе). Написал простые контроллеры и странички, проверил, что все работает, решил приступить к Hibernate. И вот начались проблемы. Но думаю начну все заново))) Это самое правильно решение)

Comment: Ну вы тогда просто не лучший пример выбрали. Вот возьмите [что-то такое](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-1-xml-configuration). Там два варианта: XML и Java конфиг, полные исходники внизу страницы. Можно также посмотреть в сторону Spring Boot, для которого можно [сгенерировать шаблон проекта со всеми зависимостями](https://start.spring.io/). В нем все что вам нужно вообще через один файл настраивается.